# foreach stops after include

Tags: php, foreach, include

Why does `foreach` stop after include (second)? Here is my code:

```
define('MONITORING_MOD', dirname(__FILE__) . '/');

$entries = scandir(MONITORING_MOD);
foreach($entries as $entry) {
    if (preg_match('%[a-zA-Z0-9_-]%', $entry)) {
        if(is_file(MONITORING_MOD . $entry) && $entry != 'init.php') {
          include_once(MONITORING_MOD . $entry);
        } else if ($entry != 'init.php') {
          $sub_entries = scandir(MONITORING_MOD . $entry);
          foreach($sub_entries as $sub_entry) {
            echo MONITORING_MOD . $entry . '/' . $sub_entry;
            if (preg_match('%[a-zA-Z0-9_-]%', $sub_entry)) {
              include(MONITORING_MOD . $entry . '/' . $sub_entry);
            }
          }
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to use `include_once`, making special function and it did not help.
Another `include_once` in this code works perfectly and outside `foreach` too.

Comment: Are you trying to build your own auto-loader? PHP already has a mechanism for that - http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php -  and using composer makes it even easier.

Comment: Yes, it's autoload, but my app don't use oop